# Using windows terminal for executing program in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I use vscode for writing and executing my C++ programs, I use the integrated terminal in vscode for compiling & running the programs(using coderunner) but I want to run my programs in the Windows terminal by default each time I run the program in vscode. Can anyone please help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Windows Terminal more easily, you can [open Windows Terminal in quake mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#open-the-quake-mode-window). The keybind is win+` by default. This could avoid using the integrated terminal at all, if you prefer.

You could also use the integrated terminal to [pass your command to Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=linux#command-line-argument-examples). Replace `ping learn.microsoft.com` with the command you want to execute. You can then send build and run commands to Windows Terminal with `wt.exe`:

```
wt ping learn.microsoft.com
```

---

Alternatively, you can configure debugging behavior for when you press `F5`. First, configure `launch.json` to launch your configured external terminal:

```json
    "console": "externalTerminal",
```

Then configure [VS Code settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings) to set the external terminal for your OS in `settings.json`:

```json
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "wt.exe",
```